# #pragma comment(linker, "/STACK:val"), which base val can be?

Tags: c++, stack, pragma

Is

```
#pragma comment(linker, "/STACK:0x04000000")
```

equivalent to

```
#pragma comment(linker, "/STACK:67108864")
```

?

Comment: You'll need to start playing with dumpbin.exe so you can sort out these questions by yourself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes  0x04000000 is the hex (base 16) representation of 67108864 (base 10)